# mouse side buttons not working in Windows Vista (jsco jnl-101k)

Tags: windows-vista, mouse, mouse-buttons

I have a jnl-101k mouse (see noiseless-mouse.com).  It doesn't have any drivers to download, and Vista reports that the driver is up to date.  However the side buttons don't work in web-browsers for back and forward.  I've tried it on another PC running Windows 7 and had the same behaviour so I'm beginning to suspect that the buttons simply aren't working.

Wondering if anyone has any similar experience or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the same question to the supplier who sent a new mouse.  The side buttons on that work fine, so turns out it was a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm using it on an old laptop running Windows XP and I must say the side buttons do work. 
But I was looking for drivers to reverse the back and forward buttons, which to me are not in the correct order.

Comment: "An old laptop" what laptop? What mouse? this is extremely vague

Comment: @Observer Did you have to install drivers for it?